# react-native-webrtc handling different camera sizes

Tags: react-native, webrtc, aspect-ratio, mediasoup

I am using `react-native-webrtc-web-shim` along with `mediasoup` for web rtc. Although I have a problem with getting correct sizes and aspect ratio. My problem is reproduceable when you try to use a react native ios camera with vertical camera mode and the other client is using the web. the aspect ratio when trying to blow up the screen is off. (I know I cant use the full width of the web screen when using react native vertical camera but how do I detect this?) I know I have to set the `RTCView` to the correct size but it does not fit the screen. I need to do something like discords viewing when video chatting.

I have tried to use `videoTrack.getSettings()` or `videoTrack.getCapabilities` but I often get something like `640 480`. I have tried using `'100%'` in the styling but the screen is very small when using something like web to web. When using `SCREEN_WIDTH` or `SCREEN_HEIGHT` the vertical camera on IOS breaks obviously but I need a way to scale the video as much as possible

In summary, How would I do something like discords video viewing but with webrtc that somewhat fits the screen depending on the camera